# Avoid intelliSense error by adding multiple DesignInstances in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am using MVVM and some code behind and I am facing the following IntelliSense error(s):

> The property 'Date' was not found in type 'MainWindow'.

If I Clean, Build/Rebuild, the error goes away for a quick moment. Once I start editing something it XAML it shows up again. One way to get around this is to set my Error List to Built instead of Built + IntelliSense.

Here's what I have:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:T_Tacoma"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:T_Tacoma.ViewModel" 
        x:Name="Tacoma" 
        x:Class="Tacoma.MainWindow"
        d:DesignHeight="300" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindow}}" ***<!-- or replace with d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:TacomaViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"  -->         
        Title="" 
        Height="857" Width="1484.582" 
        WindowState="Maximized"
        SizeToContent="Manual"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        TitleCaps ="False">
    <Grid>
        <DatePicker x:Name="vDatePick" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedDate="{Binding MDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
           <DataGrid
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
             VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" 
             ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource lowCase}" 
             x:Name="dtGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=MM-dd-yy}" Header="Date"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RegularHours}" Header="Regular Hours"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OvertimeHours}" Header="Overtime Hours"/>
              </DataGrid.Columns>
           </DataGrid>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>  
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using BespokeFusion;
using Tacoma.ViewModel;

namespace T_Tacoma
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new TacomaViewModel();

            string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
            string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
            string sYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select ID, Location, Date, Name, RegularHours, OvertimeHours from Stats.Tacoma where MONTH(Date) = @sMonth AND YEAR(Date) = @sYear", connection);

            try
            {
            connection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sMonth", sMonth));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sYear", sYear));

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }     
            connection.Close();
        }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using T_Tacoma.Model;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System.Windows;
using Xceed.Wpf;
using T_Tacoma;

namespace Tacoma.ViewModel
{
    public class TacomaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
         public TacomaViewModel()
        {
          Set...();
        }

        private int _selectedTabIndex;
        public int SelectedTabIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedTabIndex; }
            set
            {
                    _selectedTabIndex = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");
            }
        }

        public DateTime mDate = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime MDate
        { 
            get { return mDate; }
            set
            {
                if (value == mDate)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else if (_selectedTabIndex == 0)
                {
                    mDate = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    mDate = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MDate");

                    Task.Run(() =>
                   {
                      Set...();
                   });  
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

If I leave `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindow}}"` I get the error on my ViewModel properties(`MDate`, `SelectedTabIndex`). If a replace it with `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:TacomaViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"`I only get the error on the columns binded in the datagrid (`Location`, `Date`, `RegularHours`, `OvertimeHours`)

This is what I have tried hoping it would work but it didn't:

```
<DataGrid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindow}}"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" 
   ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource lowCase}" 
   x:Name="dtGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=MM-dd-yy}" Header="Date"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RegularHours}" Header="Regular Hours"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OvertimeHours}" Header="Overtime Hours"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<DatePicker d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModel:TacomaViewModel}" 
            x:Name="vDatePick" SelectedDate="{Binding MDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TabControl d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModel:TacomaViewModel} 
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
</TabControl>
```

How can I get around this without having to move everything from my code-behind to the ViewModel? I know I might not be using the best practice but is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: Looks like your window should have a `TacomaViewModel` design instance.  Your grid column bindings will continue to report IntelliSense errors because the grid has no idea what type it will be binding to.  You should really be binding the `ItemsSource` to a data set in your view model, but since you're binding to a `DataTable`, I honestly don't know whether the binding warnings will go away.  Regardless, get that SQL query out of the window's constructor.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the advice. I am comfortable with my SQL commands in the code-behind for this particular project and I would like to keep it this way. I'll keep the design instance pointing to my ViewModel but how can I change the design instance only for the Data Table? Would you be able to help with a quick workaround? Please. :)

Comment: Doing that kind of data access in the code-behind is a huge break from MVVM.  At the *very least* it should be moved to the view-model, but even that isn't great.  Ideally that should be in some kind of data repository layer, passed by constructor using dependency injection.

Comment: I'm just starting out. Thanks for the advice, Bradley. Maybe I'll be able to do what's ideally in the future.

Comment: Having the SQL query in the code behind is not the most egregious thing: putting it in the constructor is.  At least load it asynchronously so you can show a loading indicator or something.  If the query blocks for any reason, the user will have no idea what’s going on, and the window won’t even be visible.

Comment: I agree Mike. As you can see above in the ViewModel, I'm using Task.Run() for the queries and I show a loading indicator. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on it I manage to solve it by doing the following:

- Set the DataContext for the window to the ViewModel: 
  `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:TacomaViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"`
- Add another DataContext to the DataGrid (pointing to my code behind):
  `<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"...</DataGrid>`

I hope it helps others.